# Sign into Gmail and get contacts ?

Tags: android, gmail, single-sign-on

My android Application needs a Single Sign on with Facebook, twitter and Gmail. There is a alot of help on the web for using twitter and facebook. I want to enable the user, to Sign into my application using gmail and load the user's gmail contacts. Any help with this would be of great use.

Kind Regards.

Comment: Did you read about Federated login based on OpenID?

Comment: no. I am new to this. Some pointers would be of great use.

Answer (score -1):

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID

This should get you started on Google Federated login via OpenID.

EDIT:
https://developers.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/ - This is the homepage for Google API for Android

http://openid.net/developers/ - This is the dev page for open ID

For additional help I think some code is necessary :)

EDIT2
This the library for OpenID authentication with Java programs.
http://code.google.com/p/openid4java/

Comment: Thanks for this. Any example project for Android ?

Comment: Added the relevant links in the answer ;)

Comment: What i need is an Android based implementation. This links give a good overview of the OpenId implementation but i need an Android Specific project to understand the details. Hope you understand.